# TTNavigationController not working

Tags: iphone, three20

I have downloaded the latest build of the three20 library but it doesn't include the `TTNavigationController`. I looked through the files on github and found the classes there though. So I downloaded them but now I can't find it's parent class `TTBaseNavigationController` anywhere. Does anybody know what's going on with the three20 build I got?

Comment: You might wanna download it again.  It should include everything you need... Go here and click "download source" at upper right http://github.com/facebook/three20  ...then in the Finder window you can just search the entire directory for that file

Comment: Turned out when I did download source on github it didn't download everything. When I cloned the repository through the terminal it got the correct version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to import following

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>
```

The Three20.h file includes Three20UI.h, which contains the TTNavigationController.

If you are using xcode 4, see the following instruction on importing the Three20 project into your project and setting up appropriate dependency, HEADER SEARCH PATHS and static lib linking.

http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support